# Xpages Flexible View Control

Tags: datatables, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I installed your wonderful program flexible view control for XPage. Everything works great. But unfortunately I could not get her to work in a modal window or picklist. I see only the column headings and info (footer). All rows in table is absend,  but info (footer) shows real counts rows (in my case 4).

[image]

Could you tell me how to do this?

```
<!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade picklist" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose a record</h4>
            </div>


            <xc:ccRestView showFooter="true" showFixedHeader="true"
                    showFilter="true" showInfo="true" showCellBorders="false"
                    keyIsCategory="false" refreshInterval="0" multiValue="false"
                    showRefreshButton="true" showFilterText="true" scroller="true"
                    ordering="true" scrollerCount="500" thisView="ViewBasic"
                    viewKey="view-definitions"
                    dataTableClass="tableViewBasic"
                    rowCallback="ccRestView.defaultRowCallback" filterText="Поиск"
                    dataTableClassDefault="table table-striped table-bordered">

             </xc:ccRestView>


        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Oleg - see this blog post for how to get the control working with the Bootstrap modal:

https://xpage.me/2020/04/06/a-flexible-view-control-for-xpages-part-7-modals-picklists/

And you can view a working demo here:

http://demos.xpage.me/demos/datatables-xpages-bootstrap.nsf/viewPicklist.xsp

Also, in your source above you are missing the modal-body div.  This is a required component inside the Bootstrap modal.

The key to loading DataTables inside a modal is initializing the view AFTER the modal has been rendered, especially when the fixed header is being used.

Comment: Dear Michael!
You have created a great component. Thank you very much for the quick response and the opportunity to get acquainted with your developments.